# How to add a UIView above a UITableView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using the xcode template to create a UITableView application with UINavigationController.

I need to add a UIView (at fixed position) between the UINavigationBar and the UITableView. How to do that ?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by setting the UITableView's `tableHeaderView` property.

[UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **tableHeaderView**
>
> Returns an accessory view that is displayed above the table.
>
> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView
>
> Discussion The default value is nil. The table header view is
>   different from a section header.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Add UIView and UITableView as subviews of UIView and then position their height, width and x, y position from the Size Inspector in Interface builder or Use `CGRectMake` in objective-c

Comment: This method needs me to re-configure the data source and delegate of the UITableView by myself. Not friendly enough.

Comment: I think his application is navigation type which has class inherited from UITableViewController.

Comment: @user403015 If you want the UIView at the top to be fixed, this is the only way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement following UITableview delegate methods

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: These delegate methods will add the view to the **section header**, not above the tableview itself.

Comment: I am assuming there is only **one section** in tableview

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)
Create a header view as, set outlet to that view.

@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIView *viewHeader;

Setp 2) 
Add following single line code on viewDidLoad

[self.tableview setTableHeaderView:self.viewHeader];

Done!!!

Answer (score -1):

Views are maintained in a hierarchy in iOS. They are maintained essentially as an array with the latest view first. To insert some view below one view or above another you just need to manipulate this.

All this is theory, I have not done what you want. So dont hold a grudge against me ;) this is  a friendly suggestion.

`[self.view insertSubview:yourNewView belowSubview:navigationController];`

Comment: It doesn't relate with frame anyhow